# Linux setup issue with starboard for Cobalt

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cobalt, gyp, gn

I recently stumbled on to cobalt while I was looking to port my web application to android. I followed [these](https://cobalt.dev/development/setup-linux.html) steps on my Linux system. I was able to complete the 'Set up your workstation' and 'Set up Developer Tools' sections.

While building, on the following line

```
~/cobalt$ python3 cobalt/build/gn.py -p linux-x64x11
```

I get the following error messages

```
:~/cobalt2$ python3 cobalt/build/gn.py -p linux-x64x11
gn --script-executable=/home/vermaayu/.virtualenvs/cobalt_dev/bin/python3 gen out/linux-x64x11_devel
Build Accelerator: ccache
ERROR at //starboard/tools/BUILD.gn:18:15: Script returned non-zero exit code.
  file_list = exec_script(script, [ "-l" ], "trim string")
              ^----------
Current dir: /home/vermaayu/cobalt2/out/linux-x64x11_devel/
Command: /home/vermaayu/.virtualenvs/cobalt_dev/bin/python3 /home/vermaayu/cobalt2/starboard/tools/app_launcher_packager.py -l
Returned 1.
stderr:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vermaayu/cobalt2/starboard/tools/app_launcher_packager.py", line 30, in <module>
    from starboard.tools import command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starboard.tools'

See //starboard/BUILD.gn:72:5: which caused the file to be included.
    "//starboard/tools:build_app_launcher_zip",
    ^-----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vermaayu/cobalt2/cobalt/build/gn.py", line 99, in <module>
    main(builds_out_directory, known_args.platform, known_args.build_type,
  File "/home/vermaayu/cobalt2/cobalt/build/gn.py", line 51, in main
    subprocess.check_call(gn_command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gn', '--script-executable=/home/vermaayu/.virtualenvs/cobalt_dev/bin/python3', 'gen', 'out/linux-x64x11_devel']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233031/gn-build-guide-for-cobalt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674211/issue-with-running-cobalt-built-with-linux-x64x11-config), I found to be different issues than mine.

I have installed GN. I am not big on GN or GYP and limited knowledge on python.
I have tried 2 different [LTS builds from Github](https://github.com/youtube/cobalt). Looked for similar issues with starboard but didn't find much.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are running into is with Python script that is invoked by GN is not finding the code modules it needs ( starboard ) from the current directory.

`export PYTHONPATH=$PWD` should solve this.

It's also mentioned in step 6) of the instructions you linked to.